# How is the android app is automatically updated,W/o me updating it on playstore?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, uiview

How is the application updating, even if i didnt updated it?.
Like,
Amazon:- The shopping list gets updated, clothes are changed,etc. 
How is the interface changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a step back and look at REST-APIs, Databases and Network requests.

Essentially your app is asking the server for Data about items and Displays this information on your screen. The app itself doesn't hold any product information itself. I has to query the amazon server every time.